# Retrieving links searched using Yahoo and Bing

Tags: java, html, jsoup

We are currently working in a project that has [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) concept. We are not able to retrieve links for a search keyword searched using Yahoo and Bing, which is possible in Google search engine. We are using servlets and html. Could you please find a solution?

```
public static final String GOOGLE_SEARCH_URL = "https://www.google.com/search";
String searchURL = GOOGLE_SEARCH_URL + "?q="+word+"&num="+num;
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(searchURL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").get();
Elements result = doc.select("h3.r a"); 
for (Element res : result) {
    String linkHref = res.attr("href");
    linkHref = linkHref.substring(7, linkHref.indexOf("&"));
    out.println("<a href="+linkHref+">"+linkHref+"</a>");
```

The above program is retrieving links when it is searched using google. But it is not retrieving links when we change the url to Bing and Yahoo.

Comment: Then inspect the HTML source for Yahoo and Bing to see why it's not working. It's possible that they are using code that will hide the links from simple parsers such as JSoup.

Answer (score 2):

1) The way you are trying to achieve the results is wrong. **Important:** All the three search engines have different ways of showing the results.

2)You should inspect and find out the `HTML` which is shown after any search query is fired through browser. Inspect the element using browser console.

Whenever we search anything on these three search engines we get results in different form:

**On Bing**

```html
   <li class="b_algo" data-bm="8">
  <h2><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keanu_Reeves" h="ID=SERP,5133.1"><strong>Keanu Reeves</strong> - <strong>Wikipedia</strong>, the free encyclopedia</a></h2>
  <div class="b_caption">
    <div class="b_attribution"><cite>https://<strong>en.wikipedia.org</strong>/wiki/<strong>Keanu_Reeves</strong></cite>
    </div>
    <p><strong>Keanu</strong> Charles <strong>Reeves</strong> (/ k eɪ ˈ ɑː n uː / kay-AH-noo [citation needed]; born September 2, 1964) is a Canadian actor, producer, director and musician.</p>
  </div>
</li>
```

**On Yahoo**

```html
<div class="compTitle options-toggle">
  <h3 class="title"><a class=" td-u" data-sb="/beacon/clk;_ylt=A2oKmK.cOOlXskYAmKe7HAx.;_ylu=X3oDMTBycWJpM21vBGNvbG8Dc2czBHBvcwMxBHZ0aWQDBHNlYwNzcg--" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keanu_Reeves" referrerpolicy="origin" target="_blank" data-cff="57e9389d37daf"><b>Keanu</b> Reeves - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</a></h3> 
  <div><span class=" fz-ms fw-m fc-12th wr-bw">en.wikipedia.org/wiki/<b><b>Keanu</b></b>_Reeves</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**On Google**

```html
<h3 class="r"><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keanu_Reeves" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNHeNQLRv6isQkhVWpt6-1ftD0Q0vw','EZmLIYbQoBakBQ8oWWstdQ','0ahUKEwjz_KKbp63PAhVKrY8KHVnuBPUQFggcMAA','','',event)">Keanu Reeves - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</a></h3>
```

So it is not possible for your programm `Elements result = doc.select("h3.r a");`to findout the results for all the search engines.

3) The way you are restricting the search results is also not correct. You have to use different `URL query` for each of them.

**Google :** `use num=1` - `https://www.google.com/search?q=test&num=1`
**Bing :** `use count=1` - `http://www.bing.com/search?q=test&count=1`
**Yahoo :** `use n=1` - `https://search.yahoo.com/search?p=test&n=1`

**While using BingSearchURL** You can do something like below:

```
public static final String BING_SEARCH_URL = "https://www.bing.com/search";

String searchURL = BING_SEARCH_URL + "?q=" + word + "&count=" + num;
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(searchURL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").get();
    Elements result = doc.select("li.b_algo h2 a");
    for (Element res : result) {
        String linkHref = res.attr("href");
        //linkHref = linkHref.substring(7, linkHref.indexOf("&")); //No need of doing substring 
        System.out.println("<a href=" + linkHref + ">" + linkHref + "</a>");
    }
```